# Sample weighting for CNN in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a CNN implemented in Tensorflow adapted from the tutorial:
[CNN with Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn#load_training_and_test_data).

Excerpt from data_input_fn:

```
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)  
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features, labels = iterator.get_next()
return features, labels
```

Excerpt from model_fn:

```
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=labels, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(  loss=loss)
```

I’m using `tf.estimator.Estimator` and providing steps = 10000 while calling the train function. How can I provide weights to all the samples (around 3M samples) in the dataset during training? My understanding is all samples have equal weight (1/N) during training of the first model and are used to calculate a weighted loss. Then, based on calculated loss values, the weights should be modified, saved and reloaded during training of the next model. Should the weights be provided from a csv file because the original TF Record files don’t contain weights or is there a better way to do this? Also, is there an accepted function to modify the weights based on the loss values?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use sample weighting in tensorflow. Almost every loss function takes a "weights" argument which if you pass a tensor of the right shape will be used to weight the samples.

Comment: Do you have any specific info - like how to recalculate the weights from weighted loss after first iteration of training? It gets trickier because there's around 3M samples passed as batches in 10000 steps to the train function for training a model.

Answer (score 0):

AdaBoost is not usually used with neural nets. The expense of training them makes ensemble methods less attractive. So if that is what you want to do, you will probably have to implement it yourself.

If your model is a binary classifier, you can supply a class weight to tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits.